# I have a styled component that shows up in the inspection tool but it's styling don't

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass

I am trying to create a component with dynamic classNames to apply different styles based on the name. So far I can get the different names to show up when I check with the inspection tool but the styling stays doesn't change.

The button component:

```
import { ListButtonProps } from "./ListButtonProps";
import styles from "./ListButton.module.scss";

const ListButton: FC<ListButtonProps> = ({
  buttonType,
  backgroundColor,
  color,
  borderWidth,
  fontSize,
  fontWeight,
  width,
  height,
  gap,
  children,
  onClick,
}) => {

  return (
    <div
      className={[styles.listButton, buttonType].join(" ")}
      style={{
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
        color: color,
        borderWidth: borderWidth,
        fontSize: fontSize,
        fontWeight: fontWeight,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        gap: gap,
      }}
    >
      <>{children}</>
    </div>
  );
};
export { ListButton };
```

The styleSheet:

```
.listButton .title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

In the inspection tool the className is "ListButton-module-listButton_KIOLE title", and it shows the inline style but not the CSS styling.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is your style loaded? Somewhere inside your html document? Or doesn't it exist too?

Comment: Css modules generate hash for every style. You can't just concat strings and expect it to work/

Comment: The output of the css module class name won't be `.title`. You'd need to use `styles[buttonType]` to get the munged name.

Answer (score 0):

CSS modules munges the class names, so it's not going to be `.title` in the stylesheet output. You'd need to reference the type via `styles` too.

And I might be missing something (highly likely) but it's not clear to me why you're hyphenating and joining the class names.

```js
className={`${styles.listButton} ${styles[buttonType]}`}
```

Should output the module equivalent of `class="listButton title"`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a switch statement to handle the differing classNames

```
import React, { FC } from "react";
import { ListButtonProps } from "./ListButtonProps";
import styles from "./ListButton.module.scss";

const ListButton: FC<ListButtonProps> = ({
  buttonType,
  backgroundColor,
  color,
  borderWidth,
  fontSize,
  fontWeight,
  width,
  height,
  gap,
  children,
  onClick,
}) => {
  /**
   * Uses the buttonType prop to return a div with a unique
   * className to ensure scss styling adopted per div.
   * @param {string}
   * @returns {JSX.Element}
   */
  function returnStyledButton(buttonType: string) {
    switch (buttonType) {
      case "title":
        return (
          <div
            className={styles.title}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
              color: color,
              borderWidth: borderWidth,
              fontSize: fontSize,
              fontWeight: fontWeight,
              width: width,
              height: height,
              gap: gap,
            }}
          >
            <>{children}</>
          </div>
        );
      case "avatarTitle":
        return (
          <div
            className={styles.avatarTitle}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
              color: color,
              borderWidth: borderWidth,
              fontSize: fontSize,
              fontWeight: fontWeight,
              width: width,
              height: height,
              gap: gap,
            }}
          >
            <>{children}</>
          </div>
        );
      case "avatarTitleInfo":
        return (
          <div
            className={styles.avatarTitleInfo}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
              color: color,
              borderWidth: borderWidth,
              fontSize: fontSize,
              fontWeight: fontWeight,
              width: width,
              height: height,
              gap: gap,
            }}
          >
            <>{children}</>
          </div>
        );
    }
  }

  return <>{returnStyledButton(buttonType)}</>;
};
```